# Laravel testing function to see any changes in a database

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, phpunit

I need a function that would give me a list of tables and records that was done by some php code. This function is going to be executed from a unit test.

My idea to set a time by a Carbon, execute some php code, and then run this function that would get a list of all the tables in the database and run a select for each table looking for the specific date at created-at and updated-at fields..

Than it returns a collection of records created in the batabase grouped by table name.

Alternatively, if I'd be happy to get a list of modifications made by database transaction.

I don't know if such function exists somewhere on MySQL level or maybe in Laravel, or PHPUnit.

If it doesn't exist, please help me write it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solve it now:

**Function**

```
function databaseChanges(Carbon $dateTime): array
{
    $schema = config('database.connections.mysql.database');
    $tables = DB::select(
            "
                    SELECT `table_name`
                    FROM `information_schema`.`tables`
                    WHERE true
                        AND `table_type` = 'base table'
                        AND `table_schema`= ?
                "
            , [$schema]
    );
    $result = [];
    foreach ($tables as $table) {
        try {
            $records = DB::table($table->table_name)
                ->select('created_at', 'updated_at')
                ->where('created_at', $dateTime)
                ->orWhere('updated_at', $dateTime)
                ->get();
            if ($records->count() > 0) {
                $result[$table->table_name] = $records;
            }
        } catch (QueryException $ex) {
            //\Log::debug(get_class($ex));
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**Unit test**

```
class DataBaseTest extends TestCase
{

    use DatabaseTransactions;


    public function test_data_base_changes(): void
    {
        $now = Carbon::now();
        Carbon::setTestNow($now); // stop the time

        $user = factory(User::class)->create();

        $changes = databaseChanges($now);

        $this->assertSame(['accounts', 'users'], array_keys($changes));
    }


}
```